# FormsAppCompatActivity crashes when using FileProvider

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin Forms application, after adding a FileProvider to my AndroidManifest.xml then the application crashes during LoadApplication with a null reference exception if i inherit from FormsAppCompatActivity.

There have been numerous reports already (e.g https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/issues/434 or https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=36287)

I can change my base class to be FormsApplicationActivity and that avoids the problem however that is not a viable long term solution and none of the other suggested workarounds work for me.

One answer states *"But the root cause was due to the app navigating to another page while the Android 6.0 permissions dialog was shown."* however all i am doing in my app constructor is

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
```

Has anybody, using Xamarin Forms 2.5+, VS 15.5.6, with the MainActivity inheriting from FormsAppCompatActivity with a provider defined managed to successfully launch their android application?

Comment: Works fine by my side, but I'm using VS 2017, version 15.5.6 and xamarin forms version 2.5.0.122203. Are you trying to add code like `<provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="com.company.app.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
  <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
</provider>
` in your manifest?

Comment: Yes you have the same setup as me and that is exactly the code that fails, when i add the provider to the manifest file along with the XML file then the app crashes in MainActivity.OnCreate during LoadApplication(new App()); Do you derive from FormsAppCompatActivity?

Comment: Yes. I've double checked that, strange....

Answer (score 4):

I was going through the same nightmare.

It looks like that after `cleaning the solution`, `closing Visual Studio`, and `deleting the obj and bin folders` my project works fine again....

And I also set the build action of my **file_paths.xml** to `AndroidResource` but it was not working before the big cleanup. So I don't if that helps.

Enjoy!